# Any one can help me in Gmail Push notifications

Tags: python, django

I am woriking on email client app in django i want to enable realtime notification in my app i had use my service accout credential and topic name but when i enable it rase an excepion as preconditation failed

this is my code

```
def setup_gmail_push_notification():
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('automate-38413-b49e282b6eeb.json',scopes=SCOPES)
    

    # Create the Gmail API service
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    # Define your webhook URL
    webhook_url = 'https://1ad5-182-178-213-15.in.ngrok.io/Gamil/Login/gmail-webhook/'

    # Create the push notification watch request
    request_body = {
        'labelIds': ['INBOX'],  # Specify the label(s) to watch for notifications
        'topicName': 'projects/automate-83413/topics/gmail-push-notification',
        'labelFilterAction': 'INCLUDE',
        'pushConfig': {
            'pushEndpoint': webhook_url,
            'payloadFormat': 'FULL'
        }
    }

    try:
        # Send the watch request
        # request = service.users().watch(userId='me', body=request_body)
        request = {'labelIds': ['INBOX'],'topicName': 'projects/automate-383413/topics/gmail-push-notifications'}
        service.users().watch(userId='me', body=request_body).execute()
        response = request.execute()

        # Handle the push notification setup response
        print('Gmail push notification setup successful:', response)

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle authentication errors
        return(e)
```

Comment: try this https://fcm-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/